# Parse data Map from json fail, how to fix

Tags: flutter, dart

I've method search from api, data model like object, but i don't know how to parse, anyone can help me let see my code below, i have search method and api link, if u wanna other code, u can comment on column comment

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/app/models/detail_model.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/shared/constant/api_services.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/shared/services/base_client.dart';

class SearchController extends GetxController {
  //TODO: Implement SearchController
  RxBool isAwaitData = false.obs;
  // RxList<DetailModel> ;

  Future<List<DetailModel>> searchController(
      {String query = '', bool isWait = true}) async {
    if (isWait) {
      isAwaitData.value = true;
      List result = await BaseClient().get(
          baseUrl: ApiService.baseURL, api: ApiService.searchResto + query);
      // var response = await http
      //     .get(Uri.parse(ApiService.baseURL + ApiService.searchResto + query));

      return result.map((e) => DetailModel.fromJson(e)).where((resto) {
        final nameLower = resto.restaurant.name.toLowerCase();
        final cityLower = resto.restaurant.city.toLowerCase();
        final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
        return nameLower.contains(cityLower);
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
    // if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    //   final result = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(response.body));
    //    result.map((key, value) =>
    //    key.contains(result)
    //    );

    // }
  }
}


class ApiService {
  static const baseURL = 'https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev';
  static const allResto = '/list';
  static const detailPage = '/detail/';
  static const searchResto = '/search?q=';
}
```

[image: Model]

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't return a list, but a map - The `restaurants` key of the response points to a list of objects.

Try:

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = await BaseClient().get(
  baseUrl: ApiService.baseURL, 
  api: ApiService.searchResto + query
);

final restaurantData = responseData['restaurants'];

return restaurantData.map((e) => DetailModel.fromJson(e)).where((resto) {
  final nameLower = resto.restaurant.name.toLowerCase();
  final cityLower = resto.restaurant.city.toLowerCase();
  final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
  return nameLower.contains(cityLower);
}).toList();
```

Comment: u can see my model on the top, so what is solution?

Comment: Did you already try what I suggested? If so, what is still not working?